# Open another Activity upon wrong Username or Password by user in Webview

Tags: android, android-webview

I have an app which includes a custom `loginactivity` which passes username and password for `autofill` in `webview`. After that in `webview` user fills the capture and login, Now I want to redirect user to `loginactivity` again, if fails to login.

Comment: is your login activity a webpage ?

Comment: No, it is not a webpage, it has just two text fields i.e. username, password and a submit button

Comment: if it is not pages, how you are oping in webview ?

Comment: I m using onclick method for button to open MainActivity to open webview

Comment: how do you know if it fails to login?

Comment: That is the same thing, i wanna do,

Comment: so you have login page which you are loading in webview from main activity

Comment: Yes, login page is at MainActivity

Comment: webview is used to load html pages not activity layout file... if you login page designed in android xml file you can use in activity not in webview..

Answer (score 0):

If you know the url that your login page redirects to after successful login then you can do this

```
mWebView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
        @Override  
        public void onPageFinished(WebView view, String url) {
             super.onPageFinished(mWebView, url);
          //check if login url is correct & launch activity
         if(url.equal("YOUR_SUCCESS_URL"){
           //launch activity
          }

        }  
 });
```

`

Comment: Above solution is correct for them, in which redirect users to a specific URL on wrong login and password, but mine is > display:visible an element saying "Wrong Password" and URL is same as loginpage.